# How to get rid of white space on right side and bottom of entire app?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've searched high and low to find how to do this but cannot figure it out. It only shows on the right and bottom of the app:

Top of page:
[image]

Bottom of page:
[image]

It seems that the entire app has a margin set, but I've tried this CSS code below which is linked to my index.js:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Shouldn't that solve the issue? I'm sure I am missing something fundamental but not sure what it is. Also, below is my index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can provide any of my code too :)

Comment: Is your App having the default App.css imported for React projects using CRA? If not, then a look at your code will definitely help in figuring out what seems to be the issue.

Comment: Adding more code would be very helpful at finding out what the issue is, but a quick and dirty fix might be adding `max-width: 100vw;` and `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body` in CSS

Comment: https://github.com/Bolmstead/Wittmeyer_and_Associates

Comment: figured it might be easiest just to provide my entire repo. I am trying your methods now @John

Answer (score -1):

The image that you are using is not fitting the size of the screen try fixing image size